# Sending message from FusionPBX to sip agent

Tags: xml, lua, sip, freeswitch, fusionpbx

I am using `FusionPBX` as `SIP` server(registar). `FusionPBX` works fine for call and SIMPLE message routing, but I need to modify it so that I can send `SIP/SIMPLE` messages to registered users from `FusionPBX`.

I found on [freeswitch docs](https://developer.signalwire.com/freeswitch/FreeSWITCH-Explained/Modules/mod_sms_6587288/#send) site that it can be achieved from `lua` scripts or `xml` files.

Here is lua code from freeswitch docs:

```
local event = freeswitch.Event("CUSTOM", "SMS::SEND_MESSAGE");
   event:addHeader("proto", "sip");
   event:addHeader("dest_proto", "sip");
   event:addHeader("from", "1004@192.168.0.81");
   event:addHeader("from_full", "sip:1004@192.168.0.81");
   event:addHeader("to", "sip:1019@192.168.0.81");
   event:addHeader("subject", "sip:1019@192.168.0.81");
   event:addHeader("type", "text/html");
   event:addHeader("hint", "the hint");
   event:addHeader("replying", "true");
   event:addHeader("sip_profile", "external");
   event:addBody("Hello from Seven Du! Have fun!");
   
   -- freeswitch.consoleLog("info", event:serialize());
   event:fire();
```

I've tried this code with various changes but haven't achieved successful message sending from FusionPBX.

In my example I have LAN `10.10.0.0/16` where

1. FusionPBX has `10.10.10.100` IP address
2. Softphone 1 (SIP agent 1) has `10.10.20.1` IP address and SIP extension 101
3. Softphone 2 (SIP agent 2) has `10.10.20.2` IP address and SIP extension 102

The best solution would be if I could set message's headers so that FusionPBX sends message to Softphone 1, and that Softphone 1 recieves message with headers so that looks like message is sent from Softphone 2.

This will help me to implement message delivery even if some agent isn't registered, because with this functionality undelivered messages can be delivered from FusionPBX to agent when agent registers again.
I already implemented parts to save undelivered messages and this part is only missing.